# How to startup two projects calling eachother when testing?

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit

I have a problem with testing my different API endpoints. The endpoint I'm testing relies on my second API. Therefore the endpoint I'm testing relies on my other service that need to be running. When I press Run All tests in visual studio, the service my test rely on stops running.

I have tried running the service my endpoint is relying on, and running 'Run selected tests'. That seems to work.

It's the following test Im trying to make work:

```cs
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(TestDataGenerator.GetCreateAnswerCommandsFromDataGenerator),
 MemberType = typeof(TestDataGenerator))]
public async void CreateNewAnswer_ReturnsBadRequest(CreateAnswerCommand a,
                                                    CreateAnswerCommand b, 
                                                    CreateAnswerCommand c )
{
    Assert.True(await IsBadRequest(a));
    Assert.True(await IsBadRequest(b));
    Assert.True(await IsBadRequest(c));
}
```

```cs
public class CreateAnswerCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateAnswerCommand>
{
    private readonly IUserServiceClient _client;

    public CreateAnswerCommandValidator(IUserServiceClient client)
    {
        _client = client;

        RuleFor(x => x.TextTranslated).NotEmpty().NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.RequestId).NotEmpty().NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.UserId).MustAsync(IdExists).WithMessage("ID must be registered");
    }

    private async Task<bool> IdExists(Guid arg1, CancellationToken arg2)
    {
        bool exists = await _client.CheckUserId(arg1);
        return exists;
    }
```

`CreateNewAnswerCommand` has a `MustAsyns` through `FluentValidation` that calls my `UserService` and checks if the `UserId` exists.

I want the two test projects to start spinning and then close when I press Run All Tests.

Comment: Are both projects in the same solution?

Comment: Hey Tony. Yes they are in the same solution.

Comment: Is the solution setup with multiple startup projects or a single startup project?

Comment: I just tried running the tests with both services starting. Didn't seem to go through.

Comment: I'm not an expert with xunit, but I believe that you would need to setup and run the services inside of a container (EX: Docker).  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/test-aspnet-core-services-web-apps) for more information

Comment: There are a number of NuGet packages for test servers. [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests) describes Microsoft's implementation. That way instead of getting the project to run we can just start a web server from within our test project.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two project in the same solution ,right click on the first project  then choose debug and then start new instance.Finally run the tests to the other project